# Run Alarm In Selected Days

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I want to start alarm when i have selecting the days,hours,and minutes.

This is my code so far :

```
public void startAt() {
        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(backgroundApplication.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(backgroundApplication.this, 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,calendar.WEDNESDAY);
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,7);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,35);
        manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                1000 * 5, pendingIntent);
    }
```

For the example i set the DAY_OF_WEEK is today(friday) it works great. But when i changed it into Wednesday, or other day before friday it still running.

Is there any other way to start in selected days ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29, the 2nd parameter is the trigger time in milliseconds and if you set it to a time in the past, the alarm will trigger immediately. If you want the alarm to only start from next Wednesday, then you have to advance your Calendar time to the next Wednesday with `calendar.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH, 1)`. By the way, in your code, you don't need to have         `calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis())`.`Calendar.getInstance()` will return the current time by default. You should also use static field `Calendar.WEDNESDAY`.

Comment: So what i must delaring again ?

Comment: You don't have to declare again, see my appended answer.